# Routing REST requests without framework?

Tags: php, api, rest

I have been reading the article to learn how to build a rest API:

http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

At one point it says "Assuming you’ve routed your request to the correct controller for users"

How can I do this without a framework?

I am writing a REST API that I can interact with from a different application. I ready the tutorial above, and it makes sense mostly, but I don't exactly understand what it means to route my request to the correct controller for users.

Comment: If you want to do PHP MVC, not using an already existing framework is probably not advisable. If you insist on doing it yourself, then you need to further define what exactly you are trying to do, as right now, this is not answerable in its current form. Are you asking how to write something that accepts a HTTP request... an actual new MVC framework..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Apache`, you can accomplish this easily using a combination of `mod_rewrite` and some PHP-based logic.  For example, in your `.htaccess` or vhost definition, you could route all requests through a single handler, possibly `index.php`:

```
# Don't rewrite requests for e.g. assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

...then in your index.php file do something like:

```
$target = $_REQUEST['q'];
/* parse the request and include the appropriate controller PHP */
```

For example, a request for `/products/1234` might result in a `controllers/products.php` handler being included.  That handler could then act on product `1234`.  Because you're using REST, you shouldn't need to be concerned with the original request having a query string parameter.

There are multiple ways to accomplish what it sounds like you're trying to do, this is just one of them.  Ultimately what you go with will depend on what your specific requirements dictate.  The above pattern is fairly common however, many frameworks use it or something like it.

Comment: I am going to give this a try.. don't have much experience with editing .htaccess but i will try to read up on it

Comment: Great.  If you feel I answered your question, please consider accepting it.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Will do, I usually wait until i figure out the problem

Comment: just clarification.. the first line of says if the request URL is not a file that exists, use that rewrite rule?

Comment: Correct. You wouldn't want a request for, say, `/assets/js/foo.js` to be redirected to `index.php`.  So when a request is for a file that exists, the file is served. Otherwise the request will be redirected to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a matter of terminology. Every code with some level of generalization can be called "framework". And since you're asking about "routing", which provides a starting level of generalization, every implementation becomes a framework.

If you don't want to use existing fully-fledged frameworks, you can elaborate your own light-weight-implementation. Here is some articles to start:

- [Write your own PHP MVC framework](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/)
- [PHP MVC framework in one hour](http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-one)
  (the author has decided to remove this post because he thinks that using a modern fully-fledged framework is more appropriate way of programming such things, yet some people find such simple and stripped-down approache more suitable in many aspects: learning, efficiency, no huge dependencies, etc); the post is available on some other sites, for example, in the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20121215045721/http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-one) or [copies](http://phpbao.diandian.com/post/2013-03-14/40048243953)
- [The Model View Controller in PHP](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/)

All these intros include explanations of the routing mechanizm and demonstrate its implementation.

Basically, a router is a kind of internal "[DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)" (in a figurative sense) inside your application. When a request arrives to your site, you need to dispatch it to appropriate worker class, according to that request properties. This is the router's task.

Comment: I believe the op's question is pretty specific: how to route requests to an appropriate controller...*not* how to implement a MVC framework.

Comment: All documents about self-made MVCs describe the routing aspect very well.

Comment: @Goose, thank you for your notification, I'm going to update the answer.