# .htaccess rewriterule problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a few redirects in my .htaccess file, and what I've done works perfectly well in the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), but it doesn't work at all on my server. I've spent days finding a solution, and I'm stuck. It would be wonderful if someone could help!

1) "/-" in URLs
This is a good example:

```
https://www.haraldjoergens.com/galleries/remembrance-sunday/2012-cenotaph/-march-past/index.php?page=40
```

The "2012-cenotaph/-march-past" is supposed to be "2012-cenotaph-march-past"

I had though a straightforward `RewriteRule  ^(.*)/-(.*)$ %1-%2 [R=301,L]` would do the trick, but it seems to be completely ignored.

2) Repetition needs to be removed:
Due to making the "Replace" a 301 replace too early, the search engine bots try to access very wrong things:

```
https://www.haraldjoergens.com/galleries/rowing/index.php/galleries/rowing/
```

The second "/galleries/rowing" needs to be removed. My attempt via

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/index\.php)/.*$ /$1 [R,L]
```

works fine in htaccess tester, but seems to send the website into an endless loop.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Harald

Comment: The problem might have to do with a HTTPS redirect, if I comment that out, the rewrite seems to happen:  
'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]'
Of course I want the HTTPS redirect.

Comment: The problem seems to be indeed related to rewrites from not-www to www, and http to https. htaccess tester tells me: **The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect.** But I haven't found a way around the problem yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[htaccess example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14807463/5714463)

I dont know if this is what you really need.
One thing helps me is to change the routes for example:

```
$route['index.php/galleries/rowing/'] = "index.php";
```

Comment: Hi Fernando, thank you! Where would I put that statement? In htaccess, or in my PHP? In PHP it would be a problem because a lot of the code is generated, and I would have to add it any time a change to the configuration happens. A htaccess solution would be much easier.

Comment: [MVC PHP WithOut Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921249/routing-rest-requests-without-framework)

I dont know if you use any framework, in my case i use cedeigniter and it have one page for routes. But in this link explains how to create your own MVC and to change the routes.