# PHP routing without using a big framework at all

Tags: php, routes

How am I able to have like `/profile/{id}/guilds` without having to use a big router and change a lot of my code. How can I just do it within like 2 files one for `/profile/{id}` and then another one for `/profile/{id}/guilds`

Comment: You may be able to use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921249/routing-rest-requests-without-framework.

Comment: I understand that you may not want to add complex frameworks only for routing, but there is good small tool for it called Slim. Otherwise you will need to write and maintain regular expressions

Comment: Ive tried to use slim before but I cant ever get it to properly work :( I dont learn well without examples..

Comment: Have a look at http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html, shows how simple Slim can be.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I am starting to learn Slim V3 I wish I could use the latest version V4 but I just cant get it to work easily but I mean V3 should do the job for me.

Comment: Yea having issues with using it without having errors with my code. Tried changing a lot and cant get it working. I just wish there was a simple thing I could do that I dont have to make changes to every page on my site.